# How to create smart diagram using html?

Tags: html, svg, latex, converters, tikz

I have designed a smart diagram which helps the people to understand the registration process using latex.

The source code is the following.

```
 \documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{standalone}


\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[head node/.style = {shape          = rectangle,
                                         rounded corners,
                                         fill           = blue!50!black,
                                         minimum width  = 3cm,
                                         minimum height = 1.5cm,
                                         align          = center,
                                         text           = white},
                   blue edge/.style  = { ->,
                                         ultra thick,
                                         blue!40!black,
                                         shorten >= 4pt}]

% the nodes : possible  \newcommand*\dx{5} \newcommand*\dy{2}
\node[head node](wish) at (0,0) {\textbf{Wish to attend the conference?}};
\node[head node,above right =4cm of wish](register1) {Register};
\node[head node,below right  =4cm of wish, minimum width=8cm](register2) {Register};
\node[head node,right =1cm of register1](abstract) {Submit the Abstract};
\node[head node,  right =13cm of wish ](payment) {Payment};

\node[align=center,color=blue!50!black,right =3cm of payment](attend) {\bfseries\Huge  ICLAA 2017 \\ {} \\ \Large  Welcomes you!!   };

\node[right = .1cm of attend] {\includegraphics[scale=.07]{manipal}};



% edges 
\draw[blue edge]  (wish.east) -- node [pos=0.5,sloped,above,align=center] {Presenting a paper\\ /Poster/Invited Speaker} (register1.west); 

\draw[blue edge]  (wish.east) -- node [pos=0.5,sloped,above,align=center] {Presenting a paper\\ /Poster/Invited Speaker} (register1.west); 
\draw[blue edge]  (register1.east) -- node [pos=0.5,sloped,above,align=center] {} (abstract.west); 
\draw[blue edge]  (wish.east) -- node [pos=0.5,sloped,above,align=center] {Participant only} (register2.west);     
\draw[blue edge]  (abstract.east) -- node [pos=0.5,sloped,above,align=center] {Participant only} (payment.west);          
\draw[blue edge]  (register2.east) -- node [pos=0.5,sloped,above,align=center] {Participant only} (payment.west);       
\draw[blue edge]  (payment.east) -- node [pos=0.5,sloped,above,align=center] {   \includegraphics[scale=.1,angle=20]{flight} } (attend.west);        
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output is,
[image]

Now I want to upload this image as  dynamic image(I dont know this is correct word to use!!!) in website which should have links on the each 
tabs wherever necessary.

### Work done:

1. I have used htlatex to convert the latex document to html. But It converts into svg and I have an issue in the image(like that fight, univerisity photo). At any cost? Failed in this case.
2. I have uploaded the jpg file into the web directed which generated from conversion of pdf to jpg in linux and that was not pretty good.

### My Questions:

1. Is there any way to generate the complete diagram in html itself? if so, kindly provide code.
2. Is there a way to convert this latex output to html where I can add the link wherever I want?

Thank you for helping!!!

Comment: Do you need an alternate simple method to do it?

Comment: what's wrong with SVG? It's not clear what your photo problem is?

Comment: @ShinoyShaji If any, I will be happy.

Comment: Actually there are JavaScript plugins are available for doing this. That's why I asked.

Comment: @RobertLongson Will the wordpress supports svg?? Can I use links still??

Comment: @ShinoyShaji I am not good in JavaScripts if its easy to achieve I would try.

Comment: http://gojs.net/latest/samples/flowchart.html check this link..just try it

Comment: asking for plugins is off-topic here.